# Checking a remote url depending upon config

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am a new NativeScript user and I am trying to understand how to have my app make a GET call to a remote server, depending upon environment.  In Java world we pass in an environment variable, but I have not found an example (that I understand) demonstrating how my NativeScript mobile app will know which environment it is running in, and how to get values based upon that.

I am presuming that I will have a config/ with files such as
prod.conf.js and dev.conf.js - and there is where I will put in my urls and other config values.

How do I get my NativeScript (which I will eventually build into iOS) to reach those values to use in an http request upon startup.  Any example to direction to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

**Answer**:
I finally got the problem solved by using Manoj suggestion of nativescript-dev-appconfig.  For any newbie looking for help, try this:

- {PROJECT_ROOT}/config - create the environment files as *{env}.json*.  These files are just json, with name-value pairs of the values you want. In may case that is [image]

When you do your build: `tns build ios --bundle --env.config {dev | test | prod }` 
This will take the contents of the selected env.config file (ie -env.config dev and copy it as - {PROJECT_ROOT}/app/config.json .

To use it within your code,

```
import config from "../config.json";
axios.get(config.MY_URL).then(result => {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately using environment based config files are not officially supported but there is a [plugin](https://github.com/ddfreiling/nativescript-dev-appconfig) hook you could try.

We also have webpack based environment variable support, read more about that in the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/bundling-with-webpack#nativescript-cli-commands).

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can figure out webpack and deploying to local vs test vs prod.

Comment: I was able to get the plug in working so I can now run as many environments as I need.  WebPack also does support this, but I just kinda prefer the nativescript-dev-appconfig approach.  I am updating my post with the answer for future questions...